# Dashboard, radio, etc. turn on when turning key everything dies

Tags: engine, electrical, ford, starting, troubleshooting

I have a 2006 Ford Focus and I recently replaced the battery.

Everything comes on dashboard, lights, radio, etc. Then when I turn the key to ignition the lights kind of flicker and then nothing! Everything goes dead, I tried turning the key again after that happens and nothing all dead. After waiting a few minutes power returns or I have to disconnect and reconnect the battery to get power back. But I still have the same issue power back on, turn the key, all goes dead.

I tried jumping the car no luck nothing happens car will not start also replaced ignition relay thinking that was the problem. Nothing. Maybe the starter solenoid? a fuse? battery cables? ignition switch?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the sequence. I think what's happening is that you turn the key to the first position and the instrument panel lights up and the radio works – but I'm unsure about what lights are working. Can you elaborate – is it the interior lights or the headlights or??? Then, when you turn the key to the ignition portion (not all the way to the starter) everything goes out, is that right? Does anything happen if you try to run the starter? Finally, what prompted you to change the battery?

Comment: The term "recent" is subjective. How recent; one week, one month, one year? Also, new batteries can fail, so you need to have it tested in order to rule it out.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like the battery isn't solidly connected. Since trying to jump the car didn't work, I think the problem isn't with the connection between the battery cables and the battery.

Given that, the most likely place to start looking is where the battery cables attach to the car. Follow the cables and check the condition of the "other" end of the cables, if I'm right, one will be loose or corroded. It is possible that in the process of changing the battery the cables got dislodged or broke due to corrosion.

Comment: I agree with the connection assessment, but would suggest the OP first clean the terminals where they connect to the battery. I've seen it more than a few times where the terminals aren't clean and produces these exact same results. Once cleaned, everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

First think we can rule out is the battery-it's new. I'm thinking it is the ignition switch. The ignition switch feeds power to all the relays controlling the instrument cluster,starter relay etc. The ignition switch has been used continuously for 10 years eventually contacts will wear out and develop problems.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, I faced same issue. When in onnposition, everything lights up. When in ignition position everythingbgoes dead. But...when I wiggle the batter's negetive terminal, and try it, everything works fine. I think, it's the terminal issue. Not the battery.